# Finding the average of data storage in a list of masked array

Tags: numpy, average, mean, netcdf, masked-array

I need to take an average of a bunch of data in different netcdf files, that contain the following dimensions: TOTAL(TSTEP, LAY, ROW, COL)

TSTEP is the number of days in a year.

So basically i took the average of the data in a year and for each file, a masked array was storage in a list. What i want to do now is to that the average of all of this years in the list.

Just to clarify, the average is of data in each pixel. So at the end I can have a masked array with the average data through all the years.

Is there anyway I can do this average simply?

[image]

Comment: Will you please add a sample of your data? Just from the question description, it's hard to get a good idea of what's to be done.

Comment: Ok! I added a print of my list data, that i want the average

Comment: Nice! Will you please provide a sample of the dataframe as JSON? i.e., with `print(df.head(5).to_dict())` ?